# Load model by from_pretrained() then model.train()?

Tags: pytorch

I got one question about torch.
I load pre-training model like:
model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
model = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

and I read  To train the model, you should first set it back in training mode with `model.train()`.

but I don't understand how it does work. when I read document of from_pretrained(), there isn't any explanation about train().

How it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.train()` is a method of `torch.nn.Module`. It notifies the module to switch to the training mode, see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train). What exactly happens under the hood is up to the actual `Module`, in many modules it doesn't change anything, so without knowing your network we cannot say what examctly happens. But for instance in `torch.nn.BatchNormNd` it [has an effect](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d).